# How to make ingress connect to pod in my network

Tags: kubernetes

my k8s master node has Public network IP, and worker node deploy in private net. worker node can connect to master but master cannot connect to worker node.

I have tested that can deploy a pod by kubectl, the pod running on worker node and master can watch pod status. but when I deploy a ingress, and access the ingress on master node, traffic cannot go to worker node.

I use flannel network.

I have tried use ssh tunnel, but it hard to management

I don't know if there are some suggests, thanks.

Comment: welcome, please, could you tell us, where your cluster is hosted?

Comment: my master nodes on aliyun ECS and have public ip. work nodes are some physical computer in private net (e.g. work nodes are some PC in my home).

Answer (score 0):

In order for your K8s cluster to work properly, you need to [Check required ports](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/#check-required-ports) if configured between your machines.